# Laravel 5 Token Mismatch after changing domain

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, token

I am moving my site from dev to prod server.

Everything works fine on domains project.dev (localhost) and dev.project.com. Now I have copied files to project.com and... "token mismatch exception". Exactly same files are working fine on other two domains.

both dev.project.com and project.com are on same maching. Right now they even connect to same database.

Right now, after almost 2 days on google I have no idea where to search next.

I don't see hardcoded domain in any file. Also, all files looks ok to me.

This is my first laravel 5.0 (and laravel in genral) project.

Any idea where should I look now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE

The problem in this case was that the session path was not writable on the server. Solution:

```
$ cd storage
$ sudo chmod -R 755 *
```

---

ORIGINAL

I assume you get the exception after submitting a form (e.g. login form).

Could it be that you set an absolute path in the form action, containing the full path to your production environment (dev.project.com)? That way, you might be submitting your form from the project.com environment to your dev environment. So your production environment is setting a csrf token which your dev environment doesn't know anything about, causing the Token Mismatch exception.

If this is the case, just use a relative path (or named routes, ...).

Comment: No, action is correct.

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('auth.login') }}">

And it generates full path to current domain, like it should be (i think)

Comment: Ok, that seems correct. It might have something to do with sessions not working properly. Can you verify sessions work? Problem could be that the session path is not writable on the server (storage/framework/sessions).